# Can we use scipy to do faster LU decomposition for band matrices?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

We know that elimination requires roughly `1/3 n^3` operations, and if we use LU decomposition stored in memory, it is reduced to `n^2` operations. If we have a band matrix with `w` upper and lower diagonals, we can skip the zeros and bring it down to about `nw^2` operations, and if we use LU decomposition, it can be done in about `2nw` operations.

In `scipy.linalg`, we have `lu_factor` and `lu_solve`, but they do not seem to be optimized for band matrices. We also have `solve_banded`, but it directly solves `Ax=b`. How can we do an efficient LU decomposition for banded matrices and efficiently perform forward and backward elimination with banded triangular `L` and `U`?

Comment: You might be interested in the [sparse LU](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.splu) function in scipy.

Answer (score 0):

Lapack's `*gbsv` routine computes the LU decomp of an input banded matrix. 
From python, you can use either its f2py wrapper (see e.g. the source of `scipy.linalg.solve_banded` for example usage) or drop to Cython and use `scipy.linalg.cython_lapack` bindings.